# Convert floating point number 1864.78 to binary and IEEE format

Tags: c, binary, floating-point, ieee-754

I've been trying to convert the value of the S&P 500 which today is 1864.78 to how it would be represented in IEEE single precision format in memory.

Converting the left of the decimal (1864) is easy.

11101001000.

But how do I get the binary representation of the decimal (.78)?  I tried using the technique but it produces many numbers over the 8 bit exponent IEEE format:

.78*2=1.56  1

.56*2=1.12  1

.12*2=.24   0

.24*2=.48   0

.48*2=.96   0

.96*2=1.92  1

.92*2=1.84  1

.84*2=1.68  1

.68*2=1.36  1

.36*2=.72   0

.72*2=1.44  1

.44*2=.88   1 (rounded up because now we have 23 total bits)

11101001000.110001111011 = 23 bits for mantissa

Add 0 for sign

0 11101001000.110001111011

Now I need to move the decimal over 10 places

1.1101001000110001111011 x 2^10 exponent is 10 now

add a 0 bit to make full mantissa 23 bits

1.11010010001100011110110

exponent is 10 so 10 + 127 = 137

which is equal to 10001001

so 0 10001001 11010010001100011110110 which is a 32 bit number.

Does this look like a decent approach?  I tested the value and writing this question I was actually able to work through it on my own.

Testing the decimal FP with this.
http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: In general, just stop making new digits when you reach the precision limit, although IEEE 754 has rounding rules to follow, too. Many, many decimal parts will not be precisely representable in binary in this way, so you have to approximate.

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to answer the question actually because making this post I had to write my thoughts down step-by-step.  The video here really helped if anyone else has an issue walking through it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIrQtuoT5Ak

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two different conversion routines for converting the integer and fractional parts to binary. You understand how to convert `1864` to binary, but you have problems converting `.78` to binary. **Note:** you must convert the actual fraction held in *memory* for the float `1864.78` which is `1864.780029` or fraction `0.780029` *not* `0.78`. That appears where your "rounding" confusion is coming from.

To convert a fraction to its binary representation, you will multiply the fraction by `2` and if the resulting number has an integer part greater than `1`, your binary representation of that bit is `1`, if not your representation is `0`. If greater than one, you subtract `1` from the number and repeat until you have exhausted the number or reached the limit of precision in question. For example:

```
number   : 1864.78
float    : 1864.780029  (actual nearest representation in memory)
integer  : 1864
fraction : 0.780029

 2 * 0.780029 = 1.560059  =>  integer part (1) fraction (0.560059)  =>  '1'
 2 * 0.560059 = 1.120117  =>  integer part (1) fraction (0.120117)  =>  '1'
 2 * 0.120117 = 0.240234  =>  integer part (0) fraction (0.240234)  =>  '0'
 2 * 0.240234 = 0.480469  =>  integer part (0) fraction (0.480469)  =>  '0'
 2 * 0.480469 = 0.960938  =>  integer part (0) fraction (0.960938)  =>  '0'
 2 * 0.960938 = 1.921875  =>  integer part (1) fraction (0.921875)  =>  '1'
 2 * 0.921875 = 1.843750  =>  integer part (1) fraction (0.843750)  =>  '1'
 2 * 0.843750 = 1.687500  =>  integer part (1) fraction (0.687500)  =>  '1'
 2 * 0.687500 = 1.375000  =>  integer part (1) fraction (0.375000)  =>  '1'
 2 * 0.375000 = 0.750000  =>  integer part (0) fraction (0.750000)  =>  '0'
 2 * 0.750000 = 1.500000  =>  integer part (1) fraction (0.500000)  =>  '1'
 2 * 0.500000 = 1.000000  =>  integer part (1) fraction (0.000000)  =>  '1'
```

**note:** how the *floating-point* fractional value will tend to zero rather than reaching your limit of digits. If you attempt to convert `0.78` (which is not capable of exact representation as the fraction to `1864.78` in a 32-bit floating point value) you will reach a different conversion in the 12th bit.

Once you have converted your fractional part to binary, you can continue with conversion into IEEE-754 single precision format. e.g.:

```
decimal  : 11101001000
fraction : 110001111011
sign bit : 0
```

The normalization for the biased exponent is:

```
 11101001000.110001111011  =>  1.1101001000110001111011

     exponent bias: 10
 unbiased exponent: 127
 __________________+____

   biased exponent: 137
   binary exponent: 10001001
```

Conversion to 'hidden bit' format to form mantissa:

```
1.1101001000110001111011  =>  1101001000110001111011
```

Then  use the *sign bit* + *excess 127 exponent* + *mantissa* to form the IEEE-754 single precision representation:

```
IEEE-754 Single Precision Floating Point Representation

  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
 |- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -|
 |s|      exp      |                  mantissa                   |
```

Look it over and let me know if you have further questions. If you wanted a simple routine to fill a character array with the resulting conversion, you could do something similar to the following to convert a floating point fraction part to binary:

```
#define MANTISSA 23
...

/** return string containing binary representation of fraction
 *  The function takes a float as an argument and computes the
 *  binary representation of the fractional part of the float,
 *  On success, the function returns a null-terminated string
 *  containing the binary value, or NULL otherwise. The conversion
 *  is limited to the length of your MANTISSA (23-bits for single
 *  precission, 52-bits for double precision). You must insure
 *  you provide a buffer for 's' of at least MANTISSA + 1 bytes.
 */
char *fpfrc2bin (char *s, float fvalue)
{
    /* obtain fractional value from fvalue */
    float fv = fvalue > 1.0 ? fvalue - (int)fvalue : fvalue;
    char *p = s;
    unsigned char it = 0;

    while (fv > 0 && it < MANTISSA + 1)
    {   /* convert fraction */
        fv = fv * 2.0;
        *p++ = ((int)fv) ? '1' : '0';
        *p = 0;  /* nul-terminate */
        fv = ((int)fv >= 1) ? fv - 1.0 : fv;
        it++;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Technically, the exact value is 1864.780029296875, and you don't need to know it ahead of time.

Comment: I agree. The point I was trying to make is that if you simply attempt to convert the `float` value of `0.78` to binary without considering the effect of the 32-bit limit on the representation of `.78` that comes from `1864.78` you will end up with a different binary representation for the fraction -- which appeared to be where the confusion about rounding stemmed from. Perhaps I could have been a bit more clear there. I was addressing the misconception regarding '*rounded up because now we have 23 total bits*'

Comment: This is probably the most thorough response one could hope for and I can't express my appreciation enough.  So you did catch the part that was confusing me.  As I was using the method you described on .78 instead of the exact representation I was going well past the precision and had no idea what to do once past it.  So I just rounded it to 1 and by sheer luck reached the correct 32-bit representation. Also looking back on this question it's obvious that I was confusing some terminology.  My only question to you now is how did you get the exact fraction .780029 from .78?

Comment: That was the easy part. `float fvalue = 1864.78;` , then for fractional value `fv` it is `float fv = fvalue - (int)fvalue;`. That way you have the exact fractional part that is capable of being stored with `1864.78` in a 32-bit float. Glad I could help. That just means at some point in the past, I have had to struggle through the bits and pieces of the IEEE-754 conversion and I'm happy to pass along what I learned. It is a great exercise for understanding (thoroughly) how floats are handled in memory. (painful, but helpful `:)`

Comment: @KaneSchutzman, not before you finish struggling with your dive into IEEE-754, but after you have fought the fight, I've posted my [**float to IEEE-754 Single Precision Binary Representation**](http://pastebin.com/5CrHq0Gc) on pastebin. I think it is also on SO, so I don't want to double post it, but I can't seem to find it in my list of answers. Oh well -- hope it helps.

Comment: I am not really convinced that this really answers the question. The part I'm really missing here is how a compiler converts the character-string "1864.78" into the number presented in the [comment from Simon Byrne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399920/convert-floating-point-number-1864-78-to-binary-and-ieee-format/35401156#comment58512411_35401156). While this answer nicely explains how to get the binary representation of a floating point number, it does not explain how to get the binary representation of the nearest float to a decimal number.

Comment: @kvantour - I agree with the comment by Simon Byrne, the nearest value was a simple bitwise equivalent and it isn't needed ahead of time. You have the string `"1864.78"` with `"1864"` to the left of the `'.'` and `"78"` to the right. You can start with the `".78"` alone to determine the fraction part representation.

Comment: That algorithm smells like it will end up with a double-rounding.

Answer (score 1):

You're 1 bit too short: the IEEE754 binary32 format uses a 24-bit significand, but stored using 23 bits with an implicit leading 1.

So the last 2 bits are:

```
0.44*2=0.88 0           => 1
0.88*2=1.76 2 (rounded) => 0 (carry the extra bit)
```

which gives the number

1.11010010001100011110110<sub>2</sub> × 2<sup>10</sup>

You've already calculated the biased exponent (137 = 10001001<sub>2</sub>), so the resulting bit pattern can be constructed directly:

```
0 10001001 11010010001100011110110
```