# process of mapping a floating point literal to its binary representation

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee-754

Consider the exact float values around 0.3

```
1) 0.2999999523162841796875
2) 0.2999999821186065673828125
3) 0.300000011920928955078125
4) 0.3000000417232513427734375
5) 0.30000007152557373046875
```

When we write the following code in C++

```cpp
auto x = 0.30f
```

compiler has to parse the `0.30f` token and make x of type float with value `0.300000011920928955078125`. (option 3 above)

I am curious how compilers reach that value, and not the values around it. One theory is that they call `strtof` function to get the float. [Here](https://github.com/ochafik/LibCL/blob/master/src/main/resources/LibCL/strtof.c) is implementation of strtof (it is basically going through each character of the string, multiplying by a power of 10 and figuring out the location of decimal). It is not obvious to me why this method will give option 3 and not option 4 or 5.

Comment: You may find [Convert floating point number 1864.78 to binary and IEEE format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399920/convert-floating-point-number-1864-78-to-binary-and-ieee-format/35401156#35401156) helpful to understanding how the conversion is done.

Comment: have a look at the [Correctly Rounded Decimal to Floating-Point Conversion](https://www.exploringbinary.com/topics/) topics at the end of the page

Comment: Those values probably differ by 1 ULP (Unit in the Last Place).  So, option 3 is apparently the best available value in the 24-bits (not 23) of precision in binary IEEE-754 Single precision.  Are you asking for the algorithm?  It is a lot of work; don't expect the answer to fit in this forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One theory is that they call strtof function to get the float.

Indeed; they use a function comparable to `strtof`. There are open source compilers. You can look at how they parse literals. [Here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/real.c#L1957) is an implementation from GCC. It is too big to copy here. It uses GNU MPFR (multiple-precision floating-point) library.

The IEEE-754 document specifies how this conversion must behave on IEEE-754 conforming systems in the section titled *5.12 Details of conversion between floating-point data and external character sequences*. Besides conversion functions, it also applies to translation time conversions such as those of floating point literals.

Comment: Does C++ standard require IEEE-754?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin No.

Answer (score -1):

why do you care about this?

IEEE specifies float as having 23 bit significand, which is about 7 decimal places. So the binary representation of "0.3" is 0.3000000 +/- precision_loss (since 0.3 itself is not binary representable), where precision_loss is less than 0.0000001.

Furthermore, depending on how you get "0.3", the binary representation of the same decimal number could be different. For example:

```
    float n = 0.3;
    cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(25) << n << endl;
    float n1 = 0.1;
    cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(25) << n1 + 0.1 + 0.1 << endl;
```

gives the following output:

```
0.3000000119209289550781250
0.3000000014901161304869959
```

I'm not sure why you need to care about the decimal digits beyond the specified precision.