# How can I find the remainder with floating point numbers?

Tags: c

```
long long convert(float n) {
    long long result = 0;
    float rem, i = 1, step = 1,c = 2.0;
    while (n != 0) {
        rem = fmod(n,c);
        n /= 2;
        result += rem * i;
        i *= 10;
        printf("Step %.0f: %f/2, Remainder = %.0f, Quotient = %f\n", step++, 2*n, rem, n );

    }
    return result;
}
int main() {
    float n,a;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%f", &n);
    printf("enter a number:");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    n = pow(n,a);
    printf("%f in decimal = %lld in binary", n, convert(n));
    return 0;
}
```

I want to write fractional exponential decimal numbers in binary, but I can't calculate properly
and I'm getting ridiculous results.

I want to get a result like this, n = 5  a = 5/8   result = 101.101

```
2.828427 in decimal = -9223372036854775808 in binary
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 4.454 s
Press any key to continue.`
```

Comment: The biggest problem is you are returning `long long` (a 64-bit value) from a `float` -- a 32-bit value on x86 and x86_64. Why not simply use a `union` between `float` and `unsigned` to get the `unsigned` representation of the `float`? That would make it easy to output the binary representation.

Comment: I'm new to this thing, I'll be glad if I can throw an example of how to do it

Comment: Can you explain exactly what output did you expect to get from this program?

Comment: a binary number is a number expressed in the base-2 numeral system or binary numeral system

Comment: It's also how all values are stored in memory on your computer to begin with. No need for conversion, you can read the bits directly....

Comment: I'm doing it as a school homework

Comment: Here is a simple [Example Function To Output In Binary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54994017/3422102). If you use the `union { float f, unsigned u } f2u = { .f = 2.828427 }` you can then simply pass `binaryConversion (f2u.u, 32)` to get the 32-bit binary representation of the float.  Easier than [Direct conversion to IEEE-754](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35401156/3422102)

Comment: The reason for [Aliasing Through Unions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55255921/3422102) is explained there. The "strict-aliasing" rule in C is [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) It's horribly written, but the crux of it is, you cannot use a pointer of a different type to access a stored value, except when accessing through a pointer of type `char*`. Using a `union` is a valid way around the "strict-aliasing" issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help .

Comment: @NihatKerem, Please post some example input and expected output examples to add clarity to the question.